# Android - ExpandableListView change background for child items

Tags: android, background, customization, expandablelistview

I'm using `ExpandableListView` in my app and one of the complaints I get from the users is
that when the `List` item is expanded it's hard to visually distinguish where the child
item ends and next group item begins.

So I would like to change the background of the child `List` item to the different shade.

Brutal attempts that I've made so far were based on directly changing background color and text of the elements inside the child `View` item but that leads to loss of hovers and highlights. So my question is - what is a good strategy to achieve the above?

I tried `styles` and `selectors` but what really bums me is if I change background for child item then I need to add `selectors` for all combinations of focus/enabled etc. When all I'm trying to do it to overwrite a single thing.

Is there a way to inherit parent `style` and set `background` only for non-focused, enabled child item with other `styles` retained?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well. Here's what worked for me:

1. Create list_background.xml in your project's `res/drawable` directory
2. Set background value of the top level layout of your child item to the drawable above. If you are scratching your head at this point - I'm referring to the xml layout file that get's used when you create child view of your expandable list in `ExpandableListAdapter#getChildView`

Here's complete drawable file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_highlight_active" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true" 
        android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_highlight_inactive" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_window_focused="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/item_body" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/item_body" />
</selector>
```

I had to copy `list_highlight_active.xml` and `list_highlight_inactive.xml` from `/android-sdk-windows-1.6_r1/platforms/android-1.5/data/res/drawable` to the drawable directory of my project. `@color/item_body` is just a shade of gray

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered a way to "somewhat" set the background color without having to jump through the selector hoops.

As you've noted, setting the background to a solid color wipes out the selector highlights because the new background color obscures it.  Droidin has what is the normal solution: provide your own background selector with the exact colors you want.  It's a pain to say the least.

But if all you want is a little color differentiation then there is a simpler way:  alpha blend.  Set your background color with an alpha value.  For example, set background to "#BBFFFFFF".  The first two digits indicate the alpha level.  It will all blend so the background won't be a pure white and the selection highlight won't be the normal bright orange but the children will be a different color and the highlight still works.  Win-win.

Answer (score 0):

I search for similar solution.
You can try get parent View on adapter method getChieldView.
I think this parent is a parent view of your all chields.
And set background from resource to this parent.
I make it like this :

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fa_report_sub_item, null);
        View parentGroup=(View) convertView.getParent();
        parentGroup.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fa_summ_report_main_item);
    }
```